# xtable left just

Tags: r, xtable

the default of `xtable` is `\begin{center}`.  I would like to make it: `\begin{left}` and `\end{left}` as well.

Code:

```
library(xtable)
xtable(anova(lm(mpg~hp, data=mtcars)))
```

Desired outcome:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{left}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
  \hline
 & Df & Sum Sq & Mean Sq & F value & Pr($>$F) \\ 
  \hline
hp & 1 & 678.37 & 678.37 & 45.46 & 0.0000 \\ 
  Residuals & 30 & 447.67 & 14.92 &  &  \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{left}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print(xtable(anova(lm(mpg~hp, data=mtcars))) , booktabs=TRUE, caption.placement = "top",
    latex.environments = "left")
```

So `latex.environments = "left"` is the solution.

Comment: The correct solution is `latex.environments="flushleft"`; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31898709/3625022.