# How to place xtable object to the left side of page

Tags: r, knitr, xtable

**Question:** How to place xtable object to the left side of page or how to disable centering globally.

I'm struggling to figure out how to place xtable object on the left side. I have got a *.Rmd file and all this goes to the relevant r chunk.

```
require(xtable)
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1,10,1),y=rnorm(10))

Xtab <- xtable(df, digits=0, caption="\\textbf{MINIMAL/IDEAL}",  
               floating=FALSE, latex.environments = c("left"))
print(Xtab, size = "small", include.colnames=FALSE)
```

I have included the following after reading various sources (print.xtable; xtable manual etc.)

`1) floating=FALSE`
`2) latex.environments = c("left")`

I have searched SO and used some of the hints but all failed.

Comment: left side of what? of the page or of the "box" where the table is printed? Please could you provide a complete code for a .Rmd in order to allow us to test our solution.

Comment: thanks for looking into this. Yes, left side of the page. There is nothing extra in my Rmd file as what I have already provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to make quite a difference whether you pass a parameter to `xtable()` or to `print(xtable())`. The following chunk creates a table according to your data that is aligned at the left of the page in the pdf file.

````
```{r, results='asis',echo=FALSE}
library(xtable)
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1, 10, 1),y = rnorm(10))
print(xtable(df,digits=0, caption="\\textbf{MINIMAL/IDEAL}"), include.colnames=FALSE, size = "small", comment=FALSE, latex.environments="flushleft")
```
````

[image]

However, as you can see, the caption remains at the center of the page.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Yes, it works! It seems that the trick was to use `"flushleft"`. I know LaTeX, however I haven't tried this one, I would stay that this part is not very well documented.

Comment: Glad it worked. You could obtain the same result by setting `latex.environments=""`. This removes the default centering. However, I prefer stating explicitly `"flushleft"` in such cases in order to avoid undesired side effects and to make the code more clear. The effect of `"flushleft"` is evidenced by using its counterpart `"flushright"`, which in this case generates a table placed at the right side of the page.